# SIP VoIP telecom videos/talks/presentations

Tags: video, voip, sip, presentation

I am looking for good SIP, telecom and VoIP resources. In particular videos, talks and presentations that are considered "a must see" from the community.

Do you suggest anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I certainly recommend [www.voip-info.org](http://www.voip-info.org/). It's wiki-based text resource, not video as you requested, but it is good to start discover technologies, vendors etc.

Answer (score 1):

Prof. S. Sengutpa course is a must.

Here's lecture on H.323 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fxy9KVpf9OA&feature=plcp